# MySQL + EF update very slow?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, updates

I want to update about millions (or half of the millions) records into my database, but it went very slow. It took me couple of hours to update only 100,000. Do you guys have any ideas?
Basically I have process to encrypt particular column value and then update it back to database. I cant do it at database level because of code integration dependency.

sample code:

```
dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

List<Users> usersLst = dbContext.Users.AsNoTracking().Take(500000).ToList(); 

foreach (var usr in usersLst) { 
     usr.Password = this.Encrypt(usr.Password); 
     dataContext.Entry(consumer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Note: - I tried with SQL Server, it is much faster. 1M records update in 15-20 mins.

Comment: Better code? More powerful machine? It's all guesses really as we have no code to look at. And even if we did, you're the only one that could benchmark it to see which bit is slowing you down.

Comment: Updated my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Update will take too much of time, From my personal experience I am telling, Don't update if you have more then 10k data. Better way is

1. Write a sub query for that field and try to get the values what you have to update with the old data from your table.
2. Convert this select query into a view, If you are new in creating view.. just check the structure  [here](https://www.guru99.com/views.html)
3. Now write a insert query in which, you are taking values from the view which you created just now .
4. Insert won't take too much time, for me it took 10 minutes to insert 1 crore data in a table from view.
5. Even if you feel it is too much of time you can do this insert using trigger in mysql, which will take only 3 or 4 minutes.

Hope I have answered your question. Just try and give me a feedback.

Comment: My .net code using EntityFramework doing all data update.  I am not sure how I can do it as you mentioned above using Views.

Comment: Is this a one time data entry or else ,every time you have to do in your application whenever some action is needed?